# Laravel queue worker - memory isolation

Tags: php, laravel

New to PHP in general and Laravel in particular. 90% sure I know the answer to this but the documentation is *just* ambiguous enough that I'm not totally sure given my inexperience.

Laravel queue workers "store the booted application state in memory"

My reading of this is that they each have an entire copy of the application, and are completely isolated from each other in memory such that even static variables are not shared, e.g.:

- Two queue workers A and B running in parallel both have 'Name.php' with public static variable $name
- A sets $name to 'Dave'
- Time elapses. Both workers are still running.
- B sets $name to 'Alan'
- If A reads $name, it's still 'Dave'

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Nope. Worker processes are fully isolated because spawn as different processes.